# Using find / for how do I remove the original file extension for the output file name?

Tags: for-loop, replace, ffmpeg, find

When using `find` or `for` to run things on multiple files, how would I make something not keep the file extension?

For example if using ffmpeg on multiple files to convert from DTS to WAV I would run one of the following:

`find . -name "*.dts" -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:a pcm_s24le "{}.wav" \;`

or

`for f in ./*.dts; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a pcm_s24le "$f.wav"; done`

Both of these make files that end in .dts.wav rather than just .wav

**My goal is to find out what I would add/change to make the "{}.wav" or "$f.wav" *not* include the .dts part for the output file name.** (and several other examples with various extensions)

This happens automatically when using the cli version of `flac`, the output file automatically removes .wav and has .flac instead, when no output file is specified.
(Ex: `flac -8 *.wav` would create .flac files next to the .wav files, but they aren't .wav.flac, they're just .flac)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for this, e.g.:

```
find . -name '*.dts' | parallel 'echo ffmpeg -i {} -c:a pcm_s24le {.}.wav'
```

Remove `echo` when you want to execute the commands. You can control how many jobs run simultaneously with `-j N`.

#### Example

```
mkdir a b
touch [ab]/infile.dts
```

Check file-structure:

```
find a b
```

Output:

```
a
a/infile.dts
b
b/infile.dts
```

Now with `parallel`:

```
find a b -name '*.dts' | parallel 'echo ffmpeg -i {} -c:a pcm_s24le {.}.wav'
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg -i a/infile.dts -c:a pcm_s24le a/infile.wav
ffmpeg -i b/infile.dts -c:a pcm_s24le b/infile.wav
```